# How to convert WITH as SELECT query expression in python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have following query to delete the duplicates from the table in database.

```
WITH x AS (SELECT "region_code" dup, min(ctid) 
FROM  public.test2 GROUP BY "region_code"  
HAVING count(*) > 1) 
DELETE FROM public.test2  
USING     x 
WHERE     (region_code) = (dup)  AND  public.test2.ctid <> x.min 
RETURNING *;
```

Now I want to execute this query using python. When I run this query in python, nothing happens. I am using sqlalchemy with python 3.6.

```
query = "WITH x AS (SELECT \"region_code\" dup, min(ctid) FROM  " + schema + "." + table_name + " GROUP BY \"region_code\" HAVING count(*) > 1) DELETE FROM " + schema + "." + table_name +" USING     x WHERE     (region_code) = (dup)  AND  " + schema + "." + table_name +".ctid <> x.min RETURNING *;"
data = con.execute(query)
```

Comment: Maybe adding your python code would help. CTE is perfectly doable with sqlalchemy : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.HasCTE.cte

Comment: Added the python lines

Comment: What is `con`? Does it have an ongoing transaction? Do you commit? Are you connecting to the right DB? And what do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: its a connection, my same con is working for simple select, update delete individually

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what do you mean by "nothing happens". If you want the value returned, you have to fetch it: `con.execute(query).fetchall()`

Comment: I have checked on databases where the duplicate rows should be deleted that didn't happen.